# jMeter does not receive some cookies

Tags: testing, cookies, jmeter

I'm doing a test on jMeter but I came across the following problem: after doing the same requests as browser, I receive less cookies in the response compared to the actual browser. I think this problem compromises my project because there are also login requests which are missing cookies.

I'm using a Cookie Manager, which saves and sends cookies correctly when it has them stored.

I also added the `CookieManager.save.cookies=true` string to `users.properties` file as suggested around the web.

If it can help, I do not receive some cookies named `ADRUM` pretty much everywwhere, and a cookie named `ak_bmsc`.

Thank You for your suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to fix this issue by changing the HTTP Cookie Manager policy. For further information you can find the documentation [here](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/cookies.html).

Edit: I forgot to say I switched the policy to `default`

Answer (score 0):

Add to user.properties:

> CookieManager.check.cookies=true

JMeter by default validates that cookies match your domain and does not save the others.
See:

- http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Cookie_Manager

Comment: I managed to fix it by changing jMeter HTTP Cookie Manager policy. Thank you anyway!

Comment: I switched from `compatibility` to `default`